# Zend Framework call view helper from a Zend_View_Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I have a helper called `Zend_View_Helper_FormVars` that's used by one of my modules.
I also have a common helper in `application/common/helpers/GeneralFunctions.php`

I'm trying to call a function from `Zend_View_Helper_FormVars` that's in  `GeneralFunctions.php`.

Here is the short version of `Zend_View_Helper_FormVars`:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_FormVars
{
    public $reqFieldVisual='<span class="req">*</span>';
    public $roles=array('admin'=>'admin', 'user'=>'user');
    public $paymentMethods=array('1'=>'Check', '2'=>'Credit Card',
                '3'=>'Cash', '4'=>'Other');


    public function formVars(){
        $this->baseUrl=Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
        return $this;
    }

    public function mkCategoryCodeSelectGroup($codeTypeArr=array(),
        $codesArr=array()) {
        $html='';
        $html.=Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions::generalFunctions()->progressMeter();
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Here is the code in `GeneralFunctions.php`:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions
{
    public function generalFunctions(){
        $this->baseUrl=Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
        return $this;   
    }

    public function progressMeter() {
        $html='';
        $html.='<span id="progressWrapper">';
        $html.='<span id="progressMeter"></span>';
        $html.='</span>';
        $html.='';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Also, forgot to mention that I have the `GeneralFunctions` helper auto loaded in the Bootstrap like this and it's available to all my modules already:

```
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/common/helpers', 'View_Helper');
```

---

Here is what I tried, but am getting an error:

```
// application/Bootstrap.php ----------->
function _initViewHelpers() {
    // add a helper for use for all modules
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/Common/Helper', 'Common_Helper');
}
//-------------------->


// application/common/helpers/General.php ----------->
class Zend_View_Helper_General extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function general(){
        return $this;
    }   
    public function test(){
        return 'test 123';
    }
}
//-------------------->

// application/modules/dashboard/views/helpers/DashboardHelper.php ----------->
class Zend_View_Helper_DashboardHelper extends Common_Helper_General
{

    public function dashboardHelper(){
        return $this;
    }

    public function dashboardTest(){
        return 'from dashboard';
    }

}
//-------------------->

// application/modules/dashboard/views/scripts/index/index.phtml ----------->
echo $this->dashboardHelper()->test();
//-------------------->
```

Error message I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Common_Helper_General' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/application/modules/dashboard/views/helpers/DashboardHelper.php on line 2

Comment: I would recommend namespacing View Helpers with your own prefix (not Zend!) and adding the helper path for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's actually really simple to call another View Helper.

Make sure that your view helper extends `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`, so that it has access to the `$view`. Then you may simply call helpers as you would from a view, i.e.

```
$this->view->generalFunctions()->progressMeter();
```

Based on your example above:

```
<?php

class Zend_View_Helper_FormVars extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    /* ... */

    public function mkCategoryCodeSelectGroup($codeTypeArr=array(),
        $codesArr=array()) {
        $html='';
        $html. $this->view->generalFunctions()->progressMeter();
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. That worked also. There seems to be so many ways to do things with the Zend Framework. I like it, but it can be confusing at times.

Comment: The trick here was to subclass Zend_View_Helper_Abstract, something that's difficult to spot in the manual. Once you have a view reference you'll realise that you can call functions as usual. Often in ZF there are multiple ways to retrieve object references. In this case you could technically retrieve the view from the ViewRendered or a registry. My example is neatest.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly haven't configured your autoloader to load classes from the `application/common/helpers/` folder.

See `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` for default paths. You should add your new folder to this.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your class without instantiating it.

Your `generalFunctions()` function uses the `$this` pointer, which won't work; also it isn't a static method.

One option is set progress meter to be a static function and call it directly like this:

```
Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions::progressMeter();
```

Another option is to instantiate your class first.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I have the GeneralFunctions helper auto loaded in the Bootstrap like this and it's available to all my modules already:
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/common/helpers', 'View_Helper');


Hi Jai, I made it work like you said by instantiating it first like this:

$genFun=new Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions();
$html.=$genFun->progressMeter();

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your provided code.

1. You are attempting to call `Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions::generalFunctions()` as a static method when it is declared as a class method (ie you have to instantiate an instance of the class to use it) by reason of your omission of the `static` keyword.
2. If you in fact want to use `generalFunctions()` as a static method and correct this then you will need to either make `baseUrl` a static property or you will have to instantiate an instance of the class and then return that instance.
3. The idea of using your `GeneralFunctions` class as a container for static methods that are called directly is really a symptom of deeper problems and is rightly labeled a code smell. If you think that I'm lying take a look at the high priority items for the Zend Framework 2.0 (hint: it involves removing all static methods from the framework). Or you can always ask SO what they think of static methods :-).

Looking at your given class name for the general functions class `Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions` and given the current scenario where you are trying to use the `GeneralFunctions` helper inside another helper, I would surmise that you really need to do one of two things.

1. You need to have every helper class subclass the `GeneralFunctions` class so that all of your helpers have these functions available. Basically, ask yourself if your helpers all start out life as `GeneralFunction` helpers with extended functionality beyond. This solution uses inheritance to solve your problem.
2. Every view helper should contain an instance of the View object being acted upon. Therefore in theory you should be able to access any other view helper via the magic `__call` method (I think there is also an explicit method but I always use the magic method). It might look like so in your scenario:

   ```
   public function mkCategoryCodeSelectGroup($codeTypeArr=array(), $codesArr=array()) 
   {
       $html='';
       $html.= $this->generalFunctions()->progressMeter();
       return $html;
   }
   ```

   In this scenario the `__call` method would load the `GeneralFunctions` helper and would then would call the `progressMeter()` method from the `GeneralFunctions` helper.

   Now your `GeneralFunctions` helper class would probably look like this:

   ```
   class Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions
   {
       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->baseUrl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
       }

       public function progressMeter() {
           $html='';
           $html.='<span id="progressWrapper">';
           $html.='<span id="progressMeter"></span>';
           $html.='</span>';
           $html.='';
           return $html;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: But I'm interested in making my code better by what you said Noah.

So, what you're saying is that I can extend all my view helpers like this:
class Zend_View_Helper_FormVars extends Zend_View_Helper_GeneralFunctions 

And when I need a function from either of those classes in a view script for example, I would call $this->formVars()->someFunction();
And someFunction() can be in the FormVars class or the GeneralFunctions class ?

thank you

Comment: @EricP - You can extend the GeneralFunctions View Helper class with all of your View Helper classes like you're suggesting. Or, you can simply use the GeneralFunctions View Helper as a View Helper all on its own as I indicated in the sample code. Using this method, your other View Helpers still inherit the default Abstract class and then you call methods from the GeneralFunctions View Helper via the magic __call() method.